# Comment disappeared from election but shows in user profile Activity?

Tags: support, comments, election

A few minutes ago, I posted the comment pictured below on Madara Uchiha's [moderator election nomination](https://stackoverflow.com/election).

[image: Comment from profile Activity]

Moments later, the comment is no longer visible. Ok, I thought, maybe somebody flagged it and it was removed, but if that was the case it should *not* [still be visible on my profile Activity panel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/541091/michael-berkowski?tab=activity&sort=comments).

Can anyone suggest why the comment shows in my profile but not in its intended location? If it was flagged or mod-deleted, I wouldn't expect it to remain in my Activity list.

Comment: I just witnessed this too.  I posted a comment and received a reply, but neither is visible from the election page, only from my profile history

Comment: @TimStone Yes, I just noticed what was happening as you CV'd this. I went to re-post the comment, and my original plus one other reappeared, making it clear what had gone wrong.